# The '.' operator cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'

Tags: unity-game-engine, random

I have this eror:

> The '.' operator cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'
>   (CS0023)

I know that there is a question like this, but I checked it and the problem with that was put System before the method.

I have this code

```
private int posCuriosidad = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Random();
}

public void Random(){
    posCuriosidad   = Random.Range(0,9);
}
```

but I don't know why I get the error.

Comment: I would guess because of the name of your function the call is ambiguous. Use `UnityEngine.Random.Range(...)` or give your function a different name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because calling `Random.X` inside a method named `Random` will be mapped to try to invoke `X` on the method *group* of **your** method.

You clearly wanted to use the built-in `Random` *type*, not your own method.

Here's a couple of ways to do this:

1. Rename your method, "Random" is not a verb, "Randomize" is though but you should strive to make the purpose of the method clear through its name, so perhaps "RandomizePosition" would be better?

   ```
   public void RandomizePosition()
   {
       posCuriosidad   = Random.Range(0,9);
   }
   ```
2. Explicitly refer to the built-in `Random` type:

   ```
   UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,9);
   ```